# Showing a quick view div for items in page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Don't think this question is complicated by the its size. I believe this problem is simple (not for me, cause I am a beginner in web development).

First of all, I got to admit that, I am working on someone else's code. This is basically an E-commerce website, where several products are listed.

Here, I have a list of items:

```
<div id="productboxmain">

<asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" >
     <LayoutTemplate>
         <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />  
     </LayoutTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <%if (actinact == "Active")
         {%>

                    <div class="product_box">
        <div class="tumbimg">
         <a  href="Product_Details.aspx?id=<%#Eval("id") %>">
           <img src="galorg/<%#Eval("img")%>" style="max-width:168px;" border="0" />
         </a>
        </div>
        <div class="QuickViewButton">
            <img src="images/search_button.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="contwrp">
             <span><%#Eval("propertyname")%></span>
        </div>
        <div class="contwrp2">

          <span>USD <%#Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Price")).ToString("N")%></span>

        </div>

       <div class="cart_full_width">

        </div><!--end full-->

      </div>

       <%}%>

       <%else
         {%>

            <div class="product_box">
        <div class="tumbimg">
         <a  href="Product_Details.aspx?id=<%#Eval("id") %>">
           <img src="galorg/<%#Eval("img")%>" style="max-width:168px;" border="0" />
         </a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="contwrp">
             <span><%#Eval("propertyname")%></span>
        </div>
        <div class="contwrp2">

          <span>USD <%#Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Price")).ToString("N")%></span>

        </div>

       <div class="cart_full_width">

        </div><!--end full-->

      </div>

        <% } %>

     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
</div>
```

List binding code:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        ListView ListView2 = e.Item.FindControl("ListView2") as ListView;
        Label Label1 = e.Item.FindControl("lblid") as Label;
        Label lblgtotal = e.Item.FindControl("lblgtotal") as Label;
        ut.lstbind(ListView2, "select top 4 * from tbl_property where category=" + Label1.Text + " and buytype='Yes' order by id desc");
    }
}
```

**What I need to do:**

**1.** I want to add a quick view button on each item, so that when user mouse hover the item, the quick view button fades in, and fades out when mouse leave:

I did:

```
 $('.product_box').mouseenter(function (e) {
      $('.QuickViewButton').show();
  });

 $('.product_box').mouseleave(function () {
      $('.QuickViewButton').hide();
  });
```

Yes, that is working fine. The problem is that when I hover an item, the button is shown on all items. I just want to show the button on the single item only. How can I do that?

**2.** When user click the quickview button, I want to show a div with some details in it (like larger image, description, etc.). I want to show the div where I clicked (or just above the item).

I did:

```
  $('.QuickViewButton').click(function (e) {
      alert('test1');
      $('#dvQuickView').css({ 'top': mouseY, 'left': mouseX }).fadeIn('slow');
      alert('test2');
  });
```

When I click on the button, test1 alert is shown. But doesn't reach to test2 alert.

**3.** I want to show the image on that div.

I did:

```
<div id="dvQuickView" runat="server" class="dvQuickView">
    <img src="galorg/<%#Eval("img")%>" style="max-width:268px;" border="0" />
</div>
```

Ofcourse, I believe that won't work. I just copied it from the list item code.

**4.** What is this `Eval()`? I have googled it. Is it the same thing I got from google saying `javascript eval()` (because, I didn't see anything related to this kind. It was all about calculating arithmetic expressions).

**5.** Can I access the image from the div I clicked? Or is there any way to pull the image from database asynchronously?

I believe, I have explained my problems clearly. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: its easy show the image based on dynamic ids of the items bounded and also go through the listview tutorials fully

Comment: add a link button and add on click event and in that onclick event find the link button control and bind the unique dynamic id to the link button on command argument

Answer (score 0):

its easy show the image based on dynamic ids of the items bounded and also go through the listview tutorials fully

add a link button and add on click event and in that onclick event find the link button control and bind the unique dynamic id to the link button on command text

and in that event show the details as your reqirment

Eval() is used to bind the data to the listview

Answer (score 0):

By using the class selector you are selecting all elements. Try using this to create a target the current element.  Here you can add listeners to individual elements

```
        $('.item').each(function(){

           $(this).mouseenter(function()
    //event handling for the current element
                );
         );
```